# Hyperledger composer allows TLS enabled docker network or not?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

In hyperledger examples such as balance-transfer I see that the certificates of all peers are required to build a client and channel object on basis of which transactions are done. In composer I don't see the application taking into consideration those certificates for peers. Is it just because the TLS is not enabled in the docker-compose file. Is it even possible to have TLS enabled docker network yet??

Answer (score 0):

Composer can work with a TLS enabled hyperledger fabric network, you just need to create the appropriate connection profile. 
see https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/connectionprofile.html for more information